# Apk version name - jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, gradlew

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
    if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
        flavor.versionName = "Beta Revision:  ${svnRevisionDebug()}";
        flavor.versionCode = 1;
    } else {
        if (project.hasProperty('projVersion')) {
            println "Assemble release with parameter " + project.projVersion;
                    flavor.versionName = ""+  project.projVersion;
        } else {
            flavor.versionName = '10.0.0'
        }
        flavor.versionCode = 1;
    }
}
```

On Jenkins execute shell

`./gradlew assembleRelease -PprojVersion=123`

Jenkins Output console

```
+ ./gradlew assembleRelease -PprojVersion=123
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
Unix runtime
Assemble release with parameter 123
```

The output

`Unix runtime`

Come from svnRevisionDebug()

```
 def svnRevisionDebug() {
    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        println "Windows runtime"
        new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
            def result = exec {
                executable = 'svn'
                args = ['info', '-r', 'HEAD']
                standardOutput = os
            }
            def outputAsString = os.toString()
            def matchLastChangedRev = outputAsString =~ /Last Changed Rev:(\d+)/
            ext.svnRev = "${matchLastChangedRev[0][1]}".toInteger()
        }
        return svnRev
    } else {
        println "Unix runtime"
        def p = ['/bin/bash', '-c', /svn info -r HEAD | grep '^Revision:' | sed -e 's\/^Revision: \/\/'/].execute()
        p.waitFor()
        return p.text.trim()
    }

}
```

But when i decompile the apk  from the manifest I see

```
 android:versionName="1.0"
```

Wtf? 
Could be the method used with applicationVariants.all that is called multiple times while creating apk ( you see jenkins log "Unix runtime" and "Assemble release with parameter"

Which is the right way to Inject a parameter in versionName ?

Answer (score 0):

When passing a property as parameter, you should be able to access the value with the variable name itself.

Try to change `project.projVersion` in your gradle file to `projVersion`, that should work.

Meaning that the resulting line would be

```
println "Assemble release with parameter " + projVersion;
flavor.versionName = "" + projVersion;
```

Or you can try

```
flavor.versionName = projVersion.toString()
```